# On Mac OSX High Sierra, where is the bookmarks cache for Safari 11?

Tags: safari, macos-high-sierra, alfred

I recently updated to High Sierra and Safari 11. What is the location of safari bookmarks cache? For earlier versions, it used to be:

**~/Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/Bookmarks**

I use the Alfred app and need this for it to find my bookmarks.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ is a good place to post this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Alfred 3 you don't need this to find bookmarks. Just update the app. Alfred 3.5 added a [new bookmarks feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaeVA.png) and fixed the bookmark search in macOS 10.13 where macOS metadata has been removed. Look the [changelog](https://www.alfredapp.com/changelog/).